# Remove product from category using cron

Tags: category, cron

I'd like to remove products from a category after a set time (day/week).

My idea was to create a cron file, starting with this to get all products in that category:

```
$category_id = 6235;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Then remove all products from that category:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$product->getId());
}
```

Is this the right direction?
I'm getting a cron error that the catalog_category_flat table doesn't exist. Looking into the db, only catalog_category_flat_1, _2 etc exist (e.g. per store). How do I resolve this error?

Full script:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$category_id = 6235;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId(2)
    ->addCategoryFilter($category);

foreach($products as $product){
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$product->getId());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cronjobs run from the command line and unless you explicitly set a store id it will run as 0. This means `->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())` won't work. You'll have to use a fixed ID like `->setStoreId(1)`

Comment: So I changed Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() to just 2 (a store that exists) but it's still giving me the same error. Is the problem then on the line $category = ... or  Mage::getSingleton... or both?

Comment: Could you post the whole script in your question for more context?

Comment: Ok i've added the full script

Answer (score 0):

You can not use single to object and Use model object

`Mage::getModel('catalog/category_api')`

**remove**

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
```

Also as sander say you need to specify Store id

Comment: I'm now using Mage::getModel('catalog/category_api')->setStoreId(2)->removeProduct... but it's giving me this error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api::setStoreId()

Comment: you cannot use setStoreId()  on this Mage::getModel('catalog/category_api')

Comment: Understood, but after removing it, I'm back at the original error: catalog_category_flat' doesn't exist'. I have set the store id on the $category and $products lines

Comment: You can set the store ID temporarily by 
```
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
/// your code
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```