# How to Remove the items from a category automatically based on date?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, new-products, sort

I have created one category for displaying new arrivals and have added all items under this category. Now i need to delete old items (30 days old & 7 days old) from that category. This should happen daily and automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by two methods.

1) Cron

you need to create a cron which will execute as per your required time frame and make the changes accordingly.

you can follow the following url to create a cron.

[Remove product from category using cron](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68447/remove-product-from-category-using-cron)

http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

2) Observer

you need to create a observer which will execute on **controller_action_predispatch**  event and makes the changes accordingly. for creating observer you can follow the following url.

http://inchoo.net/magento/newsletter-auto-subscribe-create-account-place-order-magento/

[how to create an new observer on the event catalog_product_save_before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before)

**Code to delete product from category**

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct('7','13409');
```

where 7 is the category id and 13409 is product id

Comment: This my code : <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct('1','3');
?>  its not working